# VIM Plugin to insert image tags via NERDTree

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find/create a plugin for vim's NERDTree that will allow a shortcut to inserting HTML image tags.

Perhaps something like the solution shown here: [VIM browser plugin to execute commands on files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693389/vim-browser-plugin-to-execute-commands-on-files)

Only I can't get this to work - looks like it uses a perl script to invoke ImageMagick to determine the image dimensions and then generates an HTML tag. This script is not shown in the solution :(

Would be nice if the script would allow a selection of (multiple) images, and auto-pasted the resulting HTML into the last used position of the last used window.

Anyone know of an existing plugin like this, or steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Actually I used to do:

```
 :e /directory/where/are/images
```

(this gives me a `buffer` with directory contents, then)

```
 V
```

(selects line(s))

```
 :%s:.\+:<img src="&" />:
```

(converts the file names to `img` tags...)

```
ggVGya
```

(all the lines are selected, copied to `a` register, which can be pasted anywhere...)

HTH